# Обмен сообщениями между директивами

Tags: angularjs

У меня есть две директивы и я хотел обмениваться между ними сообщениями. Но **$scope.$broadcast** и **$scope.$emit** не работают в данном случае, так как я понимаю две директивы находятся на одном уровне типа соседи. Я решил тогда посылать сообщения через **$rootScope** и тогда всё заработало, но где-то читал, что это плохой стиль. Есть вариант делать так  - **$scope.$parent.$broadcast**. 
Вопрос - есть разница между этими двумя способами? Или лучше общаться через контроллеры? Но тогда лишние *watchers*. Или посылка и получение сообщений занимает больше ресурсов?

Comment: лучше через контроллеры. откуда лишние watchers?

Comment: все зависит от html. если директивы не связаны никак, то контроллеры не помогут

Comment: они связаны. вобщем история такая - есть ng-repeat цикл, в котором выводятся элементы. На каждом элементе висит директива, которая после прорисовки каждого элемента вычисляет его размеры, а для этого надо знать когда закончится ng-repeat и все элементы будут вставлены в DOM-дерево. 
Поэтому введена ещё одна директива в том месте, где ng-repeat, которая будет сообщать всем другим директивам, что цикл прорисовки закончился и можно уже вычислять размеры каждого выведенного элемента.

Comment: А если использовать контроллеры, то надо вводить какую-то переменную, которая будет говорить, что всё ок и элемент вставлен в DOM, можете вычислять размеры. и тогда получается надо использовать watch?

Comment: Стоит добавить в вопрос пример разметки и директив